# not able to fire the attachEvent Listener Method

Tags: javascript, html

In the below Code I have add the event Listeners on Select Combox box, 
When I change the value the event Listeners are not fired,
I am using the IE6 Browser, so used attachEvent method to fire it.

```
var td3 = document.createElement("TD")
td3.setAttribute('id','r1c3');
objSelect = document.createElement("SELECT")
objSelect.name="scuola" 
objSelect.id="sc" 

objSelect.attachEvent('change', function e(){alert("You moved your mouse over me!");  });

//objSelect.addEventListener('change',alertit,true);

var theOption=document.createElement("OPTION");
theText=document.createTextNode("Select");
theOption.appendChild(theText);
objSelect.appendChild(theOption);
td3.appendChild(objSelect);

var theOptiony=document.createElement("OPTION");
theTexty=document.createTextNode("Yes");
theOptiony.appendChild(theTexty);
objSelect.appendChild(theOptiony);
td3.appendChild(objSelect);

var theOptionN=document.createElement("OPTION");
theTextN=document.createTextNode("No");
theOptionN.appendChild(theTextN);
objSelect.appendChild(theOptionN);
td3.appendChild(objSelect);
```

I am trying to achieve, when user the changes the value in the drop down the respective alert messages should be fired...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE6 does not implement appending a text node to an option element-
you must use theoption.text='string'.

Also, the IE event type must be prefaced with 'on' in the attachEvent method.